# visual transformation for price in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to implement visual transformation for price in format "##,##,###", main problem I am facing is when I parse the string using **DecimalFormat** if the first character is 0 and then user is entering a different number application is getting crashed as the offset being returned from overridden function is out of bounds from that of array as 0 is removed by decimal format. Below is the code for implementation. I am trying to resolve this only in case of first character entered as 0. One workaround to the problem i think is converting string to number in ***onValueChange*** and then convert it into string, but it doesnt seems a good solution, looking for other solutions.

```
class PriceTransformation(private val prefix: String = "₹ ") : VisualTransformation {

override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
    var specialCharsCount = 0
    var leadingZeroCount = 0
    val zerosIndex = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val originalToTransformed = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val transformedToOriginal = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val output = prefix + text.text.toBigDecimal().formattedPrice()
    output.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
        if (output[index] == "₹".single() || output[index] == " ".single() || output[index] == ",".single()) {
            specialCharsCount++
        } else {
            originalToTransformed.add(index)
        }
        transformedToOriginal.add(index - specialCharsCount)
    }
    originalToTransformed.add(originalToTransformed.maxOrNull()?.plus(1) ?: 0)
    transformedToOriginal.add(transformedToOriginal.maxOrNull()?.plus(1) ?: 0)
    val offsetMapping = object : OffsetMapping {

        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            return originalToTransformed[offset]
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            return transformedToOriginal[offset]
        }
    }
    return TransformedText(
        text = AnnotatedString(output),
        offsetMapping = offsetMapping
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue. but i solved this problem at `onValueChange`.

this is my code :

```
var value by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    ...
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = if (it.isEmpty()) "" else BigInteger(it.filter { c -> c.isDigit() }).toString() },
    visualTransformation = ComposeVisualTransformation.Builder.Number().build()
)
```